# How to delete Safari cache using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automator

I searched this forum and I can only find how to delete history! Yet, I am interested on how to delete cache from the "Develop" menu. I do not wish to "reset" Safari neither!

I am on macOS BigSur.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to actually test this, because I really don't want my caches cleared - I use them, a lot.
However, the previous answer could probably be simplified to

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Safari" 
        activate
        close every window
    end tell
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "e" using {command down, option down}
end run
```

Assuming the Developer Menu was already activated from prefs.
I'm also assuming (again untested) that all windows need to be closed first, otherwise just the key command could be sent.

Answer (score 0):

After more searching for similar requests I put this code together. It does the job!

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Safari"
        close every window
    end tell
    set theApp to "Safari"
    set mt to 6
    set mi to -2
    tell application "System Events" to tell process theApp
        set frontmost to true
        tell menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item mt to ¬
            tell menu 1
                click menu item mi
            end tell
        tell window 1
            click button 2
        end tell
        tell menu bar item 8 of menu bar 1
            click
            click menu item "Empty Caches" of menu 1
        end tell        
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Why not just use the key command, Cmd/Opt/E ?

Comment: Automator/AppleScript is used to automate processes.

Comment: I know what automator is for, I'm just wondering why go to all this effort.

Comment: I am doing this so I can automate clearing the cache along with History using a key combination of my choice. I am not sure what your statement means. Every automation out there can be done manually yet people "go to all this effort" to automate it to make it faster, simpler and automatic!

Comment: If you want to clear History too, then add a key command to it from prefs & modify my answer below to include that key command too. You're just making this too hard, when it needn't be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really! But, I don't think you understand the entire point of automating something.

Comment: I give up. You are taking a sledgehammer to a walnut. It does not need to be this complex. Make new key command for Clear History. Make automator script to bring app to front, make necessary window closes, press two key combos. Add Automator as a Service, supply it a trigger. Done.